# HTML 5 video with unusual dimensions not showing up on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, mobile, html5-video

We have multiple videos on a website. Two sorts, full and half size. Only on the iPhone devices, the half videos won't show up. The half-sized video dimensions are 960x1080. Even when I'm directly loading the source in the browser on the iPhone, it won't load. Both Safari and Chrome. The strange thing is that the full video's with the same render settings will load. (h.264 codec etc.) The only difference is the dimension.

Did anybody encounter this problem and know a fix? (Apart from changing video with a .gif on my iPhone). I can't find any documentation on why other dimension html5-videos wouldn't work on iPhone devices.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I took a closer look into the video files. I found one difference in the render settings inside Premiere Pro. Fields: No Fields (Progressive Scan), and Fields: Upper fields first. Putting it on No Fields seems to fix the problem.